# How to encode three streams in live from a CloudStorage?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I search a lot and doesn't find anyone posted that question. If I'm wrong, I'm sorry and let me know the link please.

Here is what I would like to do. I have an application that can record his screen as well as his computer's microphone and system sound. I save the three pieces in separate files which I then send to my server.

Then I write these files directly in Azure strorage, live. Once the recording is finished, it may not be fully uploaded yet, I would like that we can already listen to what has been uploaded.

So this I would like my server to start three streams to Azure Storage (it's an easy part), put those three streams in ffmpeg and output me an output that I can stream in HTTP response.

The processing will only merge the two audio tracks and re-encode the audio in aac (it may be in opus) but I would not touch the video (which is in h264).

Also, and it seems this is a very important point, the video is in mp4 format.

Does this sound theoretically feasible? If so, any hint to helping me?

Thereafter, I will have a process that will transform the three files into a ready-to-use mp4 file so that I don't have to encode every time the file is requested. But I see no stakes for this part there.